# A numpy function for binning an array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an array `L = [1,0,5,1]` and I want to put it into two bins, I would like to get out `Lbin = [1,6]`.  Similarly let's say `L =  [1,3,5,2,6,7]` and I want to put it into three bins, I would like to get out `Lbin = [4,7,13]`.

> If `b` is the number of bins and we assume that `b` divides `len(L)`, is
>   there a numpy function to do this?

My array `L` will be large and I have a lot of them so I need a linear time solution to the problem.

---

The answer by Divakar is very nice. As an addition:

> Is there an easy way to deal with the situation where `b` doesn't
>   divide `len(L)` so the last bin just has fewer elements in it? So `L=[1,0,5,1,4]` with `b = 2` would give you `[6,5]`.

Comment: `np.reshape(L,(num_bins,-1)).sum(1)`?

Comment: @Divakar: Please make this an answer with a more detailed explanation -- only 2-3 steps, I know, but I think it's worth seeing in larger print below.

Comment: Posted as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could simply reshape to basically *split* into rows of such groups and hence sum each row for the desired output, like so -

```
np.reshape(L,(num_bins,-1)).sum(1)
```

For arrays with lengths not necessarily divisible by the number of bins -

```
def sum_groups(L, num_bins):
    n  = len(L)
    grp_len = int(np.ceil(n/float(num_bins)))
    b = int(n%num_bins!=0)
    lim = grp_len*(num_bins-b)
    p0 = np.reshape(L[:lim],(-1,grp_len)).sum(1)

    if b!=0:
        p1 = np.sum(L[lim:])
        return np.r_[p0,p1]
    else:
        return p0
```

Bringing in `np.einsum` for cases when the binned summations are within the input array dtype precision -

```
def sum_groups_einsum(L, num_bins):
    n  = len(L)
    grp_len = int(np.ceil(n/float(num_bins)))
    b = int(n%num_bins!=0)
    lim = grp_len*(num_bins-b)
    p0 = np.einsum('ij->i',np.reshape(L[:lim],(-1,grp_len)))

    if b!=0:
        p1 = np.einsum('i->',L[lim:])
        return np.r_[p0,p1]
    else:
        return p0
```

#### Benchmarking

Following closely the [`OP's timing setup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520629/a-numpy-function-for-binning-an-array#comment86047264_49520758) -

```
In [404]: # Setup
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: L = np.random.randint(0,high = 6, size = 10000000)
     ...: b = 20

In [405]: %timeit sum_groups(L, num_bins=b)
     ...: %timeit sum_groups_einsum(L, num_bins=b)
     ...: %timeit np.array([t.sum() for t in np.array_split(L, b)])
     ...: %timeit np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, b, False, dtype=int))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.25 ms per loop # @user2699's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 6.19 ms per loop # @Paul Panzer's soln
```

For the case when the array length is not divisible by the number of bins, let's have few more elements in the input array to achieve the same -

```
In [406]: # Setup
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: L = np.random.randint(0,high = 6, size = 10000012)
     ...: b = 20

In [407]: %timeit sum_groups(L, num_bins=b)
     ...: %timeit sum_groups_einsum(L, num_bins=b)
     ...: %timeit np.array([t.sum() for t in np.array_split(L, b)])
     ...: %timeit np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, b, False, dtype=int))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.45 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.05 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.45 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.51 ms per loop
```

Running those again few more times, the first one and the last two had very comparable runtimes and the second one with `einsum` was tiny bit faster than the rest.

Comment: `L = np.random.randint(0,high = 6, size = 10000000)`   `%timeit np.reshape(L,(20,-1)).sum(1)
1.08 ms ± 69.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to deal with the situation where  b doesn't divide len(L) so the last bin just has fewer elements in it? So L = [1,0,5,1,4] with b = 2 would give you [6,5]

Comment: Fast would be great but if it is linear time that is OK.

Comment: @Divakar Maybe zero-pad at the end then reshape.  Having zeros at the end then reshaping won't affect the sum of the final element.

Comment: `resize` does the filling

Comment: Can we just pad `L` with zeros to the nearest multiple of `num_bins` somehow?

Comment: @eleanora Yeah, trying to avoid any padding for performance, at least that's how I interpreted your requirement of "easy" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.add.reduceat`:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0, L.size, nbin, False, dtype=int))
```

It rounds the bin edges differently to your example, though:

```
>>> L = np.array([1,0,5,1,4])
>>> np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0, L.size, nbin, False, dtype=int))
array([ 1, 10])
```

To get your rounding:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, nbin, False, dtype=int))
array([6, 5])
```

To squeeze out a bit more performance we can avoid `linspace` and use integer arithmetic:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(L, np.arange(nbin//2, L.size * nbin, L.size) // nbin)
```

It is worth mentioning that reshape based solutions do not always give the same result as the others, in fact, there are quite a few cases where reshape simply doesn't work. Example: `50` elements, `20` groups. This requires groups of `2` and `3` elements, `10` groups each. Obviously, this cannot be done by reshaping.

Performance comparison (10 bins, element count not a multiple):

[image]

Benchmarking code:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def sg_reshape(args):
    L, num_bins = args
    n  = len(L)
    grp_len = int(np.ceil(n/float(num_bins)))
    b = int(n%num_bins!=0)
    lim = grp_len*(num_bins-b)
    p0 = np.reshape(L[:lim],(-1,grp_len)).sum(1)

    if b!=0:
        p1 = np.sum(L[lim:])
        return np.r_[p0,p1]
    else:
        return p0

def sg_einsum(args):
    L, num_bins = args
    n  = len(L)
    grp_len = int(np.ceil(n/float(num_bins)))
    b = int(n%num_bins!=0)
    lim = grp_len*(num_bins-b)
    p0 = np.einsum('ij->i',np.reshape(L[:lim],(-1,grp_len)))

    if b!=0:
        p1 = np.sum(L[lim:])
        return np.r_[p0,p1]
    else:
        return p0

def sg_addred(args):
    L, nbin = args
    return np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, nbin, False, dtype=int))

def sg_intarith(args):
    L, nbin = args
    return np.add.reduceat(L, np.arange(nbin//2, L.size * nbin, L.size) // nbin)

def sg_arrsplit(args):
    L, b = args
    return np.array([t.sum() for t in np.array_split(L, b)])

perfplot.save('cho10.png',
              setup=lambda n: (np.random.randint(0, 9, (n,)), 10),
              n_range=[2**k for k in range(8, 23)],
    kernels=[
    sg_reshape,
    sg_einsum,
    sg_addred,
    sg_intarith,
    sg_arrsplit
        ],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='#elements',
    equality_check=None
    )
```

Comment: The sg_intarith timing result is very interesting! Thank you for the lovely graph too.

Answer (score 1):

The following works,

```
array([t.sum() for t in array_split(L, b)])
```

And if, as you stated, you know that `b` divides `L` evenly, you can replace `array_split` with the `split` function.

Here's some benchmarks, with `b=100` and `L = randint(0, 100, 1000)`

```
%timeit sum_groups(L, b)  # Defined in Divakar's answer
8.09 µs ± 293 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit array([t.sum() for t in array_split(L, b)])
260 µs ± 2.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, b, False, dtype=int))
15.9 µs ± 1.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and with with `b=3` and `L = randint(0, 100, 1000)`

```
%timeit sum_groups(L, b)
23.2 µs ± 317 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit array([t.sum() for t in array_split(L, b)])
16.2 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.add.reduceat(L, np.linspace(0.5, L.size+0.5, b, False, dtype=int))
15 µs ± 1.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Depending on your data, it looks like Divakar's answer using reshaping may be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for this!